# Deleting selected rows from a DataGrid in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, datagrid

I added a checkbox in a DataGrid using ItemRenderer. I have pasted the code I am using below.

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dgEmployeeInfo" dataProvider="{resultArray}" x="131" y="95" editable="false">          
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Select" rendererIsEditor="true" editorDataField="selected">
                <mx:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <mx:HBox>
                            <s:CheckBox id="testChk" click="testChk_clickHandler(event)" selected="{cbSelected}">                                   
                            </s:CheckBox>
                            <fx:Script>
                                <![CDATA[
                                    [Bindable]
                                    public var cbSelected:Boolean; 
                                    protected function testChk_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
                                    {
                                        cbSelected = testChk.selected;  
                                    }
                                ]]>
                            </fx:Script>
                        </mx:HBox>
                    </fx:Component>
                </mx:itemRenderer>
            </mx:DataGridColumn>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="First Name" dataField="firstName"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Last Name" dataField="lastName"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="City" dataField="city"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Employee Code" dataField="empCode"/>             
        </mx:columns>       
    </mx:DataGrid>
```

I also have a button outside the DataGrid, and when this button is clicked, I want to delete all rows which have a checked CheckBox. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HI!

First of all, your code will not work properly, since not every DataGrid row has its own ItemRenderer instance. There are exactly n item renderer instances for a DataGrid having n VISIBLE rows. You can check this easily, if you create DataGrid, that can not fit all the data and then select some rows and scroll datagrid up/down. You'll see unexpected results.

One of solutions could be having additional field "selected" (or whatever you want to name it) in resultArray item properties. Then you can access this property through "data" object of ItemRenderer. Check the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">


    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            [Bindable]
            private var resultArray:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection
                                                ([
                                                {firstName:"1-1",lastName:"1-2",city:"1-3",empCode:"1-4"},
                                                {firstName:"2-1",lastName:"2-2",city:"2-3",empCode:"2-4"},
                                                {firstName:"3-1",lastName:"3-2",city:"3-3",empCode:"3-4"},
                                                {firstName:"4-1",lastName:"4-2",city:"4-3",empCode:"4-4"},
                                                {firstName:"5-1",lastName:"5-2",city:"5-3",empCode:"5-4"},
                                                {firstName:"6-1",lastName:"6-2",city:"6-3",empCode:"6-4"},
                                                {firstName:"7-1",lastName:"7-2",city:"7-3",empCode:"7-4"},
                                                {firstName:"8-1",lastName:"8-2",city:"8-3",empCode:"8-4"},
                                                {firstName:"9-1",lastName:"9-2",city:"9-3",empCode:"9-4"},
                                                {firstName:"10-1",lastName:"10-2",city:"10-3",empCode:"10-4"},
                                            ]);

            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                for (var i:int=0; i< resultArray.length; i++)
                {
                    if (resultArray[i].selected == true)
                    {
                        resultArray.removeItemAt(i);
                    }
                }

                dgEmployeeInfo.invalidateList();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>



    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:VGroup>
        <mx:DataGrid id="dgEmployeeInfo" dataProvider="{resultArray}" x="131" y="95" editable="false">          
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Select" rendererIsEditor="true" editorDataField="selected">
                    <mx:itemRenderer>
                        <fx:Component>
                            <mx:HBox>
                                <s:CheckBox id="testChk" click="testChk_clickHandler(event)" selected="{data.selected}">
                                    <fx:Script>
                                        <![CDATA[
                                            [Bindable]
                                            public var cbSelected:Boolean; 
                                            protected function testChk_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
                                            {
                                                data.selected = testChk.selected;  
                                            }
                                        ]]>
                                    </fx:Script>                                
                                </s:CheckBox>
                            </mx:HBox>
                        </fx:Component>
                    </mx:itemRenderer>
                </mx:DataGridColumn>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="First Name" dataField="firstName"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Last Name" dataField="lastName"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="City" dataField="city"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Employee Code" dataField="empCode"/>             
            </mx:columns>       
        </mx:DataGrid>
        <mx:Button label="Delete Items" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
    </s:VGroup> 


</s:Application>
```

I used ArrayCollection as dataProvider as it is much mor easier to add/remove items to Collection objects then with Arrays.

Regards.

Comment: thanks for this, but what if i am fetching data from  database, should i add a new field to database for checkbox values..?

Comment: Do you need to delete Database records as well?

Comment: @user594979. Then concentrate on the way how to identify DataGrid row with database record. You absolutely don't have to add selected field to your database. Continuing with my example you could add some code to button1_clickHandler when detecting that resultArray[i].selected == true. In the code perform SQL DELETE command constructing statement like "DELETE FROM _SOME_TABLE_ t WHERE t.firstNameField=" + resultArray[i].firstName + " and t.lastNameField=" + resultArray[i].lastName". Probably fetching some recordId field to resultArray would be best practice. Readrds. David.